# Is there custom validation of meta values in Wordpress REST API?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

WordPress allows registering meta values in the REST API through [`register_meta()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_meta/).

One can add a schema to the meta like so:

```php
register_meta(
    'user',
    'my_meta_key',
    array(
        'type'         => 'array',
        'description'  => 'This is my array meta key!',
        'single'       => true,
        'show_in_rest' => array(
            'schema' => array(
                'type'  => 'array',
                'items' => array( 
                    'type' => 'string',
                    'format' => 'date-time',
                ),
            ),
        ),
    )
);
```

It took me some time to find out about the `'format' => 'date-time'` option.

I would like to validate my meta fields myself (for a custom post-type). But it seems like the [`WP_REST_Posts_Controller`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/) uses [`get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_controller/get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema/) to set up the schema for arguments in [`register_rest_route()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/).

[`register_rest_route()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_rest_route/) would allow for a custom `validate_callback`, but [`rest_get_endpoint_args_for_schema()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_get_endpoint_args_for_schema/) hard-codes it to [`rest_validate_request_arg()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_validate_request_arg/), which uses [`rest_validate_value_from_schema()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_validate_value_from_schema/).

And there are the primitives and hard-coded formats `hex-color`, `date-time`, `email`, `ip` and `uuid`.

So there are two options I see:

1. **Live with it.** Just accept the validating against schema primitives, since the schema is only validated on REST requests.
2. **Extend [`WP_REST_Posts_Controller`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/)** just to sneak in my own [`get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_controller/get_endpoint_args_for_item_schema/), which adds an exception for my meta key.

Do you have another idea, how to solve this issue?

EDIT: There seems to be a [`pattern` property](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/schema/#pattern) for strings. So I could at least do something like (don't mind the regex itself):

```php
'schema' => array(
    'type'    => 'string',
    'pattern' => '[0-9]/[0-9]^$',
),
```

Comment: you have 3rd option, apply your all custom validation in controller or method when it successfully passes the schema level  or did you check the latest version 5.6.0 here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/rest_validate_value_from_schema/#changelog

Comment: @Noman I can't see how I can add a custom validation function there. Can you please explain?

Comment: Your rest api must use a controller or method where you perform the insertion or updation. a sample guide for your custom endpoints https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#examples

Comment: @Noman Following the example I would register a completely new route, but I just want to add meta to posts/users.